# How to select the rows of a dataframe where two variables have value

Tags: r, dataframe, select, rows

So I have a dataframe: df1. And I want to select the rows based on the value of two variables != NULL.

For example:

```
Variable1    Variable2

NULL         5

6            NULL

NULL         NULL

3            6

1            9
```

Result:

```
Variable1   Variable2

3            6

1            9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 <- data.frame(Variable1 = c("NULL", 6, "NULL", 3, 1), Variable2 = c(5, "NULL", "NULL", 6, 9))
df1 <- df1[df1$Variable1 != "NULL" & df1$Variable2 != "NULL",]
```